# Is it possible to show text in buffer *helm-occur" dynamically("on fly")?

Tags: helm

Windows 10, Emacs 25.1.

I open helm-occur and enter text "dalvik".

Then I open console and start some process that show in console many times text "dalvik".

See screenshot:

[image]

But in buffer helm occur nothing show.
But if close buffer **helm occur** and start again command "helm-occur" , enter text "dalvik" then in buffer **helm occur** success show text "dalvik".

**Question: Is it possible to show text in buffer *helm occur" dynamically("on fly")?**

Comment: I think that's not easy with helm-occur. But if you want to insert certain lines of a log into a buffer, you can modify the process filter.

Comment: Here help: https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/issues/1843